# How to calculate complex functions in Fortran which are not easy to separate into real and imaginary components?

Tags: math, fortran, complex-numbers

I need to calculate a complex function for different `x` values, something like

```
(i+1) exp(i * x) / x
```

I see that my option is to expand it in terms of `sin` and `cos`, and then separate out real and imaginary parts manually by hand, to be able to calculate them individually in code, and then define my complex function. This is a relatively simple function, but I have some bigger ones, not so easy to segregate manually into two components.

Am I missing something or this is the only way?

EDIT : I am pasting the sample code which works after helpful comments from everyone below, hope it's useful :

```
program complex_func
  IMPLICIT  NONE
  
Real(8) x
complex CF

x = 0.7
call complex_example(x, CF)
write(*,*) CF

end program complex_func


Subroutine complex_example(y, my_CF)

  Implicit None
  Real(8) y
  Complex my_CF
  complex, parameter :: i = (0, 1)  ! sqrt(-1)
  my_CF = (i+1) * exp(i*y) / y
  
  !my_CF = cmplx(1, 1) * exp(cmplx(0.0, y)) / y !!THIS WORKS, TOO
  write(*,*) my_CF
  
  return
  
end Subroutine complex_example
```

Comment: The FORTRAN EXP function supports complex arguments !?!

Comment: Try something like `cmplx(1, y=1) * exp(cmplx(0.0, y=x)) / x`. Many intrinsics are overloaded for complex arguments.

Comment: Not even necessary to use cmplx for `(i+1)`, it is just `(1, 1)`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Note it is officially spelt Fortran, lower case. And yes, complex is a first class type in Fortran so the (vast majority of) the intrinsic types support it.

Comment: @IanBush: I was referring to the versions I practiced most, namely FORTRAN IV and FORTRAN 77. :-)

Comment: Thanks, everyone! And thanks @jack, what you suggested worked perfectly!

Comment: This works, too!

`complex, parameter :: i = (0, 1)`
`(i+1) * exp(i*x) / x`

Comment: You shouldn't be using hard-coded kind values no more, e.g. `real(8)`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/838310/10774817) for more info.